# can we fetch values from database and display them in selectbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<select name="zone"  id="zone" style="width:100px; height:22px; float:left; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;">


<?php
    $sql33="select * from tb_zone where nation='Domestic'";
    $query33=mysql_query($sql33);
    while($row33=mysql_fetch_array($query33)) {
?>

<option value="<?php echo  $row33['zone_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row33["zone_name"]; ?></option>

<?php  } ?>

</select>
```

Hello as above there is a simple script in PHP that is fetching values from database and displaying it. My question is can we do the same task in JavaScript. Means can we fetch values from database and display them in `<select>` in JavaScript?

Comment: You can use javascript(AJAX) to access that code and display the result into the form as u said but you cannot do the javascript connect to the database and retrieve the data as it is client side. [Here is a very simple example of what I mentioned using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298401/basic-php-and-ajax), you can also make the JQuery insert the data directly to the form in question.

Comment: Javascript can't connect to database as for now

Comment: ohk so if i apply ajax..then i have to call other page where this select query have to be written right??

Comment: @user3181292 yes, that is how it would work.

Comment: is this for performance issues, is `$sql33` an indication of 33+ querys on the page. If so ajax wont help make a bad thing good.

Comment: no that's just a name 33 means nothng...its just a name that i have given to the uery

Answer (score -1):

The trick is to use AJAX to do it. If you're using jQuery read up on using $.ajax here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/