# Code PHP passed to HTML through append doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, html, append

I am trying pass this code for html but not work, load as text.

HTML:

```
<div id="captcha-wrap">
<p>
</p>
<!-- show the captcha result - fail/pass -->
<div id="captcha-status">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#captcha-wrap").append("&lt;?php require_once('_control/showcaptcha.php'); ?&gt;");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't append PHP like that. Have a look at using [AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298401/basic-php-and-ajax).