# send information to database without having page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a site where you type into a text box and it will send what I wrote to my database.

I have been stuck with my page having to reload which is very troubling in my case. i am not familiar with ajax but i have heard it can be used to complete this task. i have 2 files one is called demo.php this sends the information to the server and at this time has a header that redirects me back to that page which i don't want.

I want to be able to keep sending things data to the sever without the page reloading. the other page is the index.php this is were i right into the text box and send the text to my database both files are listed below.

this is the demo.php

```js
<?php
header("Location: http://mywebsite.com"); 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$value = $_POST['firstname'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname) VALUES ('$value')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "working";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

this is the forum on index.php were i enter the information and send it. i need it to stay on that page and not reload in any way.

```js
 <form action="demo.php" method="post" />
<p> <input id="textbox" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter What You Want Your Message To Be" /></p>
<input id="textbox1" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

my second attempt at index.php

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="navigation.css href="navigation/navigation.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="navigation/navigation.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<form action="ajax_target.php" method="post" id="ajax-form">
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
<input type="button" name ="send" onclick="return f(this.form ,this.form.fname ,this.form.lname) " >
</form>
</body>

<script>
function submitForm(form){
    var url = form.attr("action");
    var formData = $(form).serializeArray();
    $.post(url, formData).done(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
$("#ajax-form").submit(function() {
submitForm($(this));
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic PHP and AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298401/basic-php-and-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

You can have two files/pages for your purpose:

```
1. Form page
2. Ajax processing page where you request values will be inserted into your database.
```

Add this to your head tag

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Steps to utilize ajax:

```
1. Include jquery library in form page
2. Include html form
3. Save values from ajax, that means process that ajax
```

HTML form suppose to be like this:

```
<form action="ajax_target.php" method="post" id="ajax-form">
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
<input type="submit" name="send" value="send" >
</form>
```

Ajax call:

```
    function submitForm(form){
    var url = form.attr("action");
    var formData = $(form).serializeArray();
    $.post(url, formData).done(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
$("#ajax-form").submit(function() {
submitForm($(this));
return false;
});
```

`ajax_target.php` handles formData, its validation and insertion to database.

Comment: in my case how would i add php requests and insertion because i have no idea were to put the function.

Comment: in the same manner, how you kept for demo.php, here in your case ajax_target.php is your demo.php

Comment: what area would i place the function

Comment: and were do i call the call jQuery library in your head tag

Comment: below the html form, preferably in footer.

Comment: jquery library in the head tag.. obvious.. mentioned in my answer. already!!

Comment: how would i call it in the head tag

Comment: jquery library!!! great!!! https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js

Comment: add this to your head tag <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: @ameenulla0007 jQuery doesn't need to be included in head tag, it's just an opinion.

Comment: ill add the function in as a <script> below the forum

Comment: oh @Jack i didn't check your age, great!! appreciable.. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp.. check the tutorial for more info.

Comment: hi i have added the code at the end which is of my forum page index.php please check it

Comment: you have missed double quote there in your edited html while linking css.

Comment: its not uploading to my database

Comment: check my updated answer. and go through your do's and don'ts in your source.

Comment: what do you mean do's and don'ts whats that

Comment: my ajax is in my form i haven't added anything to ajax_target.php

Comment: obvious, you need to add your statements there, means your insertion to database..

Comment: ok at the moment the button isn't working but if i press enter the page loads up a press link which takes me to a twitter page i have in my code for some reason

Comment: no thats all i have in my ajax_target.php i only have the code from what i have above which is under demo.php

Comment: Mr. @Jack, seems like i need to tell you all in depth. Okay, will post you another answer. read it carefully, and try out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101465/discussion-between-jack-and-ameenulla0007).

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="navigation.css href="navigation/navigation.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="navigation/navigation.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="ajax_target.php" method="post" id="ajax-form">
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
<input type="submit" name ="send" value="send" >
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.51/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var options = {
            beforeSend: function () {
                   if (!confirm('Are you sure to submit ?')) {
                                return false;
                            }
                     },
            success: function (response) {
                            alert(response);
                   },
            error: function (response) {
                            alert(response);
                    };
                 }
                    $('#ajax-form').ajaxForm(options);
    });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

updated your index.php

Comment: all scrips now in my head but when i type something in and press the button it still isn't coming up in my database

Comment: Please use document.ready and try it - $(document).ready(function(){ $('#form_id').ajaxForm(); });

Comment: and put all this in script in a php file which  is index.php which has the forum in it

Comment: use input type = submit instead of button . <input type="submit" >

Answer (score 1):

your html/index form consists

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="demo.php" method="post" id="ajax-form">
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
<input type="submit" name="send" value="send" >
</form>
</body>

<script>
function submitForm(form){
    var url = form.attr("action");
    var formData = $(form).serializeArray();
    $.post(url, formData).done(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
$("#ajax-form").submit(function() {
submitForm($(this));
return false;
});
</script>
</html>
```

your demo.php includes

```
<?php
//your db insertion goes here.
echo "inserted successfully";
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say the message is coming up but its still not showing in my database.

Comment: all the initiation code works fine without the ajax but its now not uploading at all

Comment: if there is an alert "inserted successfully", it means the ajax is working fine. now you need to add up your insertion query and statement in demo.php.

Comment: i have everything in and everything as i should have

Comment: if i had my old way everything would upload but this way nothing is actually geting sent to my database through the ajax

Comment: ill continue this tomorrow