# Populating an array through jquery AJAX in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a function in a compare.php that takes a parameter $data and uses that data to find certain things from web and extracts data and returns an array.

```
function populateTableA($data);
```

So to fill array I do this

```
$arrayTableA = populateTableA($name);
```

now this array is then used to iterate tables..

```
<table id="tableA">
<input type="text" name="search"/><input type="submit"/>
<?php foreach($arrayTableA as $row) { ?>
  <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['place']?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now what I want to do is to enter some data on input and then through jquery ajax

```
function populateTableA($data);
```

should be called and    $array should be refilled with new contents and then populated on tableA without refreshing the page.

I wrote this jquery but no results.

```
$(document).on('submit',function(e) {
e.preventDefault();  // Add it here 
 $.ajax({ url: 'compare.php',
 var name = ('search').val();
     data: {action: 'populateTableA(name)'},
     type: 'post',
     success: function(output) {
                  $array = output;
              }
       });
});
```

I have been doing web scraping and the above was to understand how to implement that strategy... original function in my php file is below

```
function homeshoppingExtractor($homeshoppingSearch)
{
$homeshoppinghtml = file_get_contents('https://homeshopping.pk/search.php?category%5B%5D=&search_query='.$homeshoppingSearch);
$homeshoppingDoc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); 
if(!empty($homeshoppinghtml)){
$homeshoppingDoc->loadHTML($homeshoppinghtml);
libxml_clear_errors(); 
$homeshoppingXPath = new DOMXPath($homeshoppingDoc);
//HomeShopping
$hsrow = $homeshoppingXPath->query('//a[@class=""]');
$hsrow2 = $homeshoppingXPath->query('//a[@class="price"]');
$hsrow3 = $homeshoppingXPath->query('(//a[@class="price"])//@href');
$hsrow4 = $homeshoppingXPath->query('(//img[@class="img-responsive imgcent"])//@src');

//HomeShopping
if($hsrow->length > 0){
    $rowarray = array();
    foreach($hsrow as $row){
        $rowarray[]= $row->nodeValue;
       // echo $row->nodeValue . "<br/>";
    }
}
if($hsrow2->length > 0){
    $row2array = array();
    foreach($hsrow2 as $row2){
        $row2array[]=$row2->nodeValue;
       // echo $row2->nodeValue . "<br/>";
    }
}
if($hsrow3->length > 0){
    $row3array = array();
    foreach($hsrow3 as $row3){
        $row3array[]=$row3->nodeValue;
        //echo $row3->nodeValue . "<br/>";
    }
}
if($hsrow4->length > 0){
    $row4array = array();
    foreach($hsrow4 as $row4){
        $row4array[]=$row4->nodeValue;
        //echo $row3->nodeValue . "<br/>";
    }
}
$hschecker = count($rowarray);
if($hschecker != 0) {
    $homeshopping = array();
    for($i=0; $i < count($rowarray); $i++){
        $homeshopping[$i] = [
        'name'=>$rowarray[$i],
        'price'=>$row2array[$i],
        'link'=>$row3array[$i],
        'image'=>$row4array[$i]
        ];
    }
}
else{
    echo "no result found at homeshopping";
}
}
return $homeshopping;
}
```

Comment: put your php file code, have you tried console.log(output) will it shows any data

Comment: Check the updated question

Comment: Php is a server-side language, javascript is client side, from the moment javascript is getting executed, Php is already executed. You can't update a php variable in javascript.

Comment: The function  `populateTableA` is in php or in javascript?

Comment: have you tried debug your ajax call for php file using echo exit?

Comment: So there is no way to reload table contents without affecting the other tables?

Comment: Yess @rahul log was emply!

Comment: @AmanRawat everything is in compare.php and the function populateTableA of course in php

Comment: try echo '123';exit; check will it gives response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments PHP is a server side language so you will be unable to run your PHP function from javascript.

However if you want to update `tableA` (without refreshing the whole page) you could create a new PHP page that will only create `tableA` and nothing else.  Then you could use this ajax call (or something similar) -

```
$(document).on('submit','#formReviews',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'getTableA.php', //or whatever you choose to call your new page
        data: {
            name: $('search').val()
        },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            $('#tableA').replaceWith(output); //replace "tableA" with the id  of the table
        },
        error: function() {
            //report that an error occurred
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So basically here is the plan! I am going to create a new php file that would only create table and then call it through ajax and put its html in a div

Comment: Yeah that's what I'd suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You are doing it in wrong way.You must change your response to html table and overwrite older one.

```
 success: function(output) {
              $("#tableA").html(output);
          }
   });
```

In your ajax page create a table with your result array

Comment: please look it his compare.php there are several changes needed to work with ajax

Answer (score 0):

You are in a very wrong direction my friend.

First of all there are some syntax error in your JS code.

So use [JavaScript Debugging](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp)
to find where you went wrong.

After that [Basic PHP with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298401/basic-php-and-ajax#answer-5298448)
to get a reference how ajax and PHP work together

Then at your code

1. Create a PHP file where you have to print the table part which you want to refresh.
2. Write an AJAX which will hit that PHP file and get the table structure from the server. So all the processing of data will be done by server AJAX is only used for request for the data and get the response from the server.
3. Put the result in your html code using JS.

Hope this will help