# Cascading dropdown list in Codeigniter not working

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

In one of my View, i have a modal popup containing 2 dropdown lists (ddlPublications & ddlEditions).On page load, ddlPublications will be populated while ddlEditions will remain empty.However, ddlEditions will be populated on the onchange event of ddlPublications.

### View

```
<div class="modal-body" style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Publication</label>
            <select id="ddlPublication" name="ddlPublication" class="form-control" onchange="load_editions(this.value)">
                <option value="0">--select--</option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($pub_data as $key => $pdata) {
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $pdata['pub_id'];?>"> <?php echo $pdata['pub_title'];?> </option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Edition</label>
            <div id="edn_div_data">
                <select id="ddlEdition" name="ddlEdition" class="form-control">
                    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function load_editions(pub_id){
        alert(pub_id);
        var p_id = pub_id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>pmachine/pages/get_editions/"+pub_id,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result){
                $("#edn_div_data").html(result);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                $("#edn_div_data").html("Sorry, something went wrong");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

### CONTROLLER

```
public function get_editions($pubid)
{
    $data['edn_data'] = $this->Process_pages_model->pop_editions($pubid);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

### Problem

ddlEditions is not getting populated.It shows the message 'Sorry, something went wrong'.Please suggest what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Whats your http response code?

Comment: What do you see in developers console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what the issue could be here because I see several places it could be failing.  First of all, make sure you have debugging on.  You can use the built in profiler https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/profiling.html or I believe you can use xdebug with a little manual setup.  Now let's debug.

1. Start by replacing url in your ajax request with an actual url.  So replace

   `<?php echo base_url(); ?>pmachine/pages/get_editions/` with the actual url, something like

   `localhost/pmachine/pages/get_editions/`
2. Try creating a simple ajax example to make sure you have a good handle on it.  Here is a question about basic php/ajax examples that you can use for reference:

   [Basic PHP and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298401/basic-php-and-ajax)
3. Try echoing $data['edn_data'] rather than just $data.
4. Echo a string rather than $data to make sure you're even getting a response.
5. print_r($this-> Process_pages_model->pop_editions($_POST['pubid'])); to make sure you're getting the info from the database.  If you're not getting anything, make sure you're connecting to your database with a basic connection test:

   ```
   // Create connection
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

   // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   } 
   echo "Connected successfully";
   ```
6. print_r($_POST['pubid']); to make sure you're getting your post data
7. Try returning the data without encoding it as JSON and remove the 
   `dataType:json` from your ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your ajax pist function and your controller like this:

```
$data['edn_data'] = $this-> Process_pages_model->pop_editions($_POST['pubid']);
```

Ajax call

```
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>pmachine/pages/get_editions/" 
         data: {pubid: pub_id},
         dataType: "json",  
         cache:false,
            success: function(result){
                $("#edn_div_data").html(result);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                $("#edn_div_data").html("Sorry, something went wrong");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax success function replace the whole 'edn_div_data', which I doubt you rebuild the DOM within the result.

Try to console.log the result, and assume the result is:

```
{"edn_data":[{"edn_id":"1","edn_title":"Edition 1"},{"edn_id":"2","edn_title":"Edition 2"},{"edn_id":"3","edn_title":"Edition 3"}]}
```

and replace your ajax success function become like:

```
success: function(result){
    for (var i = 0; i <= result.edn_data.length - 1; i++) {
        $("#ddlEdition").append("<option value='"+result.edn_data[i].edn_id+"'>"+result.edn_data[i].edn_title+"</option>");
    }
},
```