# How to pick random row from mysql

Tags: javascript, php

```
<button onlick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<?php
   function myFunction() {
        $con = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.no", "u452849516_altge", "password", "u452849516_altge"); 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM altbruker ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        mysqli_query($con, $query);
        $results = mysqli_query($query);
        var_dump($results); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to do better? And where are you having issues?

Comment: I have improved my post, Samuel.

Comment: Still do not see where the problem you are having comes from... Do you get any errors or anything along those lines?

Comment: You better change your password now as well

Comment: wops, changed the password now haha

Comment: And i don't get any errors. When i click on the button now, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

you mixed up !
from html element onclick attribute you can't fire php function !
you should make request via ajax to server and in response send data from mysql
for example : 
in index.html make ajax request to server.php 
in server.php connect to database and return data 
simple ajax example :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5298448/2210325

Answer (score 0):

js on click cant call a php code you can use AJAX to do that as the following

```
<button>Click me</button>

$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "the_php_page.php", success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }});
});
```

in the the_php_page.php do the query

```
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.no", "u452849516_altge", "password", "u452849516_altge"); 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM altbruker ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        mysqli_query($con, $query);
        $results = mysqli_query($query);
        var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Now i get this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in /home/u452849516/public_html/index.php on line 24"

Comment: did you add the php tags (<?php ) before the code ?!