# Populate values from database in a table using PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have a table that has the orders and I want when each order has entered the database I want it to be displayed in the table without refreshing the page and without pressing any button. Here is the code in PHP and HTML:

```
<?php
  require_once '../core/init.php';
  if(!is_logged_in()){
    header('Location: login.php');
  }
  include 'includes/head.php';
  include 'includes/navigation.php';

?>
<!-- Orders To Fill -->
<?php
  $txnQuery = "SELECT t.id, t.cart_id, t.first_name, t.last_name, t.description, t.txn_date, t.grand_total, c.items, c.paid, c.shipped
    FROM transactions t
    LEFT JOIN cart c ON t.cart_id = c.id
    WHERE c.paid = 1 AND c.shipped = 0
    ORDER BY t.txn_date";
  $txnResults = $db->query($txnQuery);
?>

<div class="col-lg-12">
  <h4 class="text-center">Orders To Ship       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" style="font-size:23px;"></span></h4>
  <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <th></th><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Total</th><th>Date</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php while($order = mysqli_fetch_assoc($txnResults)): ?>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="orders.php?txn_id=<?=$order['id'];?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Details        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a></td>
          <td><?=$order['first_name']. ' '.$order['last_name'];?></td>
          <td><?=$order['description'];?></td>
          <td><?=money($order['grand_total']);?></td>
          <td><?=pretty_date($order['txn_date']);?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Please, how to do that in AJAX?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298401/basic-php-and-ajax

Comment: I saw that link, but still I can't do this in table :( Can you please help me!

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to research first on how to use Jquery AJAX. It's pretty easy.
Create your PHP file containing the request to the database

```
<?php
      require_once '../core/init.php';
      if(!is_logged_in()){
        header('Location: login.php');
      }
      include 'includes/head.php';
      include 'includes/navigation.php';
      $txnQuery = "SELECT t.id, t.cart_id, t.first_name, t.last_name, t.description, t.txn_date, t.grand_total, c.items, c.paid, c.shipped
        FROM transactions t
        LEFT JOIN cart c ON t.cart_id = c.id
        WHERE c.paid = 1 AND c.shipped = 0
        ORDER BY t.txn_date";
      $txnResults = $db->query($txnQuery);

while($order = mysqli_fetch_assoc($txnResults)){
    $data = "
        <tr>
          <td><a href=\"orders.php?txn_id=\". $order['id'] ."\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\">Details<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign\"></span></a></td>
          <td>".$order['first_name'].  " ". $order['last_name'] ."</td>
          <td>".$order['description'] ." </td>
          <td>". money($order['grand_total']) ."</td>
          <td>". pretty_date($order['txn_date']) ."</td>
                </tr>
        ";
}
echo $data;
?>
```

Then create the front end file that will get a request to the php file you created

```
<script>
function getdata(){
    $.ajax({
                url : "LINKTOYOURPHPFILE.php",
                success: function(data){
                    $("#table-to-be-inserted").html(data);
                }
        });
}
  //Call the function
   getdata();
</script>

<div class="col-lg-12">
  <h4 class="text-center">Orders To Ship       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" style="font-size:23px;"></span></h4>
  <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <th></th><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Total</th><th>Date</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-to-be-inserted">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

That's a simple request. Here's a link of the Jquery Ajax, Please study it well [CLICK ME TO STUDY JQUERY AJAX!!!!](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Ok, thank you. I made a PHP file called shipping.php and I added the PHP code and then I go back to the index.php where the original code was (The code that I wrote in the question) deleted the code and added the ajax code with the html code. But I got an empty table whenever data enters the database ...

Comment: Sorry didn't call the function. View the edited version

Comment: Ok, I got an error now that says **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'btn' (T_STRING)**. It means this line `<td><a href=\"orders.php?txn_id=". $order['id'] ."\" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Details<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign\"></span></a></td>`

Comment: It's just a escape character error. I just write the answer in here.

Comment: What do you mean ?? How to fix this ?? I just copied your code as it is...

Comment: Now, I'm getting a new error **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)**. I'm afraid maybe it's from the button, I really don't know :(

Comment: can you please show the line where the error occur? It's just a error in string parsing

Comment: On line 18, this line `<td><a href=\"orders.php?txn_id=\". $order['id'] ."\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\">Details<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign\"></span></a></td>`

Comment: Black P, just realized it's a new problem, and seems the ajax request is working. Please post another question regarding to this problem.

Comment: What is the new problem ?? And what should I post in another question ?? Please help me :(

Comment: You see I your first question was to use ajax request in getting the data from php. And it works because there are no related ajax problem came up. Just a string parsing error.  For the sake of your new problem can you add a console.log(data) after the line $("#table-to-be-inserted").html(data); and add it in here.

Comment: Did you see the console output in the debug mode?

Comment: When I press ctrl+right mouse button and choose inspect and went to console section I have this error `<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-parse-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in ... on line <i>18</i></th></tr>
</table></font>`

Comment: And what is the line 18 in your php file?

Comment: The problem is `<a href=\"orders.php?txn_id=\". $order['id']` You either don't intend to escape that last quote, or you need another. I'm guessing the second.

Comment: And there goes my blind eye.

Comment: You see the escaped last quote was needed for the ending value of the href attribute

Comment: Ok, I fixed the error and here is the result. When I refresh the page only the first row is shown from the database. Second, all the values are in the same column not each value in its corresponding column ...

Comment: And in the console it says: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: use concat in the $data, didn't see that, $data .=