# How can I make my anchor tag transfer information from my table?

Tags: php, html

I have an anchor tag that displays a users name and clicked it is supposed take  you to their profile page. I created a form with a post method that I need for accessing that users profile. How can I make the anchor tag act as the form?

I need the post method with the form to access that user's profile page. $post is a varaible from a foreach loop.

```
<a href = "profiles.php"  id = "name1"><h1>'.$post["UserID"].'</h1></a> 
<form action = "profiles.php"  method = "POST" >
    <input type="submit" class="post id= "nameid" name="id" value= "'.$post["UserID"].'">
</form>
```

Comment: `$post` is not a standard variable. You're looking for `$_POST["UserID"]` (and even then you should be sanitizing the user input).

Comment: "How can I make the tag equal the form?"  Can you please try to re-phrase this?  As asked, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Read up a little on Xhr / [Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298401/basic-php-and-ajax) I think.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I assumed $post in this case was referring to something like a blog post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you handle the link with client-side code instead of just letting it be a link, you can't.

The anchor will send a GET request, while your form is sending a POST request.

If you're okay with that, you can append the user id to the query string in the href.

```
'<a href="profiles.php?id='.$post["UserID"].'" id="name1"><h1>'.$post["UserID"].'</h1></a>'
```

Then you can get the id from `$_GET['id']` in profiles.php. That may not be what you want to do if you don't want the user id in the URL. In my opinion would be fine though, and maybe even preferable. That would make it easier for a user to bookmark their profile.